# How to Assign tags for treeview Nodes with multiple classes and properties

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have about 4-5 classes which are nested with super class the create hold pointers for other classes that hold and orginze information in order to display it in 2 separate treeviews windows. now the problem I have is when I try to display some text in textbox when mouseclick eventfrom treeview is event triggered. I tired to use tag property and assign it with pointer to children nodes but for some reason it only return objects with rootclases nodes and not their children nodes.

[image: IMG]

here is the part in which I assign object tag:

```
foreach (HostClass ptr in HostClassHolderlist)
{
 subpcirootnode = pcirootnode.Nodes.Add("PCI CONFIG REGISTERS");

 foreach (KeyValuePair<string, UInt32> entry in ptr.PrintHT)
 {
        treeView1.CheckBoxes = true;
        uint tmp = entry.Value;
        subpcirootnode.Tag = ptr;//hostclass pointer
        subpcirootnode.Nodes.Add(entry.Key.ToString() + ":  0x" + tmp.ToString("X"));
  }
}
```

here is the part in which I get the error in:

```
   void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    //handler for mouse click,this method show on textbox info on field
    {     
        try
        {
            int num = e.Node.Text.IndexOf(" ");
            String key = e.Node.Text.Substring(0,num-1);
            //MessageBox.Show(key);
            HostClass ptr = (HostClass)e.Node.Tag; // <-this is the tricky part of my code!!
            textBox1.Text = ptr.PcidescDict[key];
         }
     }
```

Do you have any suggestions about how to construct it properly?

Comment: Post the code where you are assigning the value and trying to read it. What youre trying to do should work fine.

Comment: the code is a bit long(about 3000 lines with multiple classes),I could show the part in my code that I try to read tag value and get exception in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You aren't assigning a tag to the child node:

```
subpcirootnode.Nodes.Add(entry.Key.ToString() + ":  0x" + tmp.ToString("X"));
```

So change that to:

```
TreeNode tn = new TreeNode(entry.Key.ToString() + ":  0x" + tmp.ToString("X"));
tn.Tag = ptr;
subpcirootnode.Nodes.Add(tn);
```

Don't know enough about your code, but all of the child nodes get the same class reference, so it's not clear what benefit that is.  You could get the same information by just checking if the e.Node.Parent class isn't null, and check the Tag property on the parent.

Comment: I changed it to use e.Node.Parent instead, thanks for your tip, otherwise I wouldn't thought about it.